# Finding observations partially matching a field from another dataset

Tags: sql, sas, string-matching

The case is the following: I have two datasets. From the first one, I need to find every observation containing in `field` any one number found in `field2` from the second dataset.

First data set:

```
field
-----
dsggagfa 837 dgfsdg
879 thh
gasgg 7999 ghth
```

Second data set:

```
field2
------
837
879
```

Expected results:

```
field
-----
879 thh
fegfrsg 879 thh
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
select * 
  from firstdata 
 where field like in (select field2 from seconddata);

 or

select * 
from firstdata 
where field in %"select field2 from seconddata"%;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If the rows in field2 were flipped (i.e. "879, 837"), would your desired result be the same? In other words, are you comparing row1 of dataset1 with row1 of dataset2 or with ANY row of dataset2?

Answer (score 2):

This will work, given your field2 from table 2 is numeric. Also, using `prxmatch` with `\b`'s (word boundaries), assures you don't select erroneously, for instance, "gasgg 7999 ghth" if your table 2 contains number 799 (or 999, 79, 99).

```
data t1;
  input field $32.;
  datalines;
dsggagfa 837 dgfsdg
879 thh
gasgg 7999 ghth
;

data t2;
  input field2 8.;
  datalines;
837
879
;

proc sql;
  select t1.field
    from t1, t2
   where prxmatch(cats("/\b",strip(put(t2.field2, 8.)),"\b/"), t1.field);
quit;
```

### Results

```
field
-----
dsggagfa 837 dgfsdg
879 thh
```

Comment: Am I think right if I write this: select a.* 
       from firstdata a, seconddata b
          where index(a.field, ' '||strip(b.field2)||' ') I will get the same result? 
       ;

Comment: Well, only if you systematically have blank space before and after the number in t1.field. And even so, unless you see a downside for using `prxmatch`, I'd recommend using the latter. `\b` means word delimiter, which can be a blank space, but also beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming field2 is a string this will work.
  `index` will return the position of `field2` in `field`.
  The where condition is TRUE when `field2` is found in `field`.

```
select a.* 
       from firstdata a, seconddata b
          where index(a.field, b.field2)
       ;
```

Comment: I had the same answer I was about to publish.  The only difference is that you need to remove leading and trailing spaces from `field2` using the `strip` function. `index(a.field, strip(b.field2))`

Comment: If `field2` is numeric then use `where index(a.field,strip(put(b.field2,best12.)))`